# Virtual machine with support for OpenGL

Tags: opengl, cloud, virtual-machine, glx

We have an application that we want to compile, auto-build and auto-test on an virtual machine. The virtual machine "provider" has to be able to be cross-platform as we require this operation to be executed on both windows and several linux distrubtions at the same. Our application is 
dependent on OpenGL, and require a rather new version of OpenGL in order to work properly.

We have decent experience with Oracles Virtual Box, where we are able to perform the above action with some effort, since we can hardware acceleration through the host-machine.
However it is somewhat limited as it is quite demanding on the host-machine, and it is not really well-suited for many virtual boxes running at the same time.

So ideally a solution could be Amazon EC2 cloud computing, but here we run into the 'usual' problem with, that we might be able to get a linux distribution (for instance Ubuntu) up and running with ease, but hits a very hard wall once we want to start installing some OpenGL drivers in order to be able to compile and test our application. Even mesa-drivers is impossible to get up and running to a degree that one can run glxinfo or glxgears.

We can't be the only one facing this problem, so what do other do ?

Comment: VMware has significantly better graphics support than Virtual Box, although there are still some oddities. Doesn't help much with EC2, but if you're doing local VMs, it might.

Answer (score 0):

> Even mesa-drivers is impossible to get up and running to a degree that one can run glxinfo or glxgears.

Mesa should always be able to fall back to `swrast` or `llvmpipe`. However for anything that uses GLX to work you need an X server. Instead of using Kdrive based servers (like Xvfb) I recommend using the regular Xorg server with the `dummy` driver. You'll have to write an `xorg.conf` for that.

Comment: Tried the way you suggest, like explained here https://techoverflow.net/2019/02/23/how-to-run-x-server-using-xserver-xorg-video-dummy-driver-on-ubuntu/

glxinfo -display :0 still complains with
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0"

note: i did export MESA_LOADER_DRIVER_OVERRIDE and LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE