# How do I fake OpenGL in an Azure Virtual Machine?

Tags: opengl, azure, virtual-machine

I'd like to run some programs in my Azure VM (Windows Server 2008), that require OpenGL 2.0.

However the VM has no video hardware :), how can I fake the programs into believing I have a good enough video card?

How am I supposed to get to the point of all development in the cloud, if I can't have virtual video cards? :)

Comment: How and why would you want to do that?

Comment: How was the question that I asked, that's what I'm trying to figure out.Why? I can think of many reasons, one is simply development (in the cloud) of something that calls on OpenGL (be it to render or just crunch numbers).

Comment: What did you try then? and what doesn't work?

Comment: Other people would like to do this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960253/virtual-machine-with-support-for-opengl?rq=1), I'm just wondering if it is possible on an Azure VM (since I get the free credits per month).   What doesn't work, is any program that calls on or requires OpenGL. On some programs I can use Orca to modify msi installers to NOT require such things. Sometimes this will work, sometimes this will allow installation but then the program fails. Do you have any help or insight to the question at hand, I'm not quite sure what the purpose of your comments are?

Answer (score 6):

You could place a Mesa softpipe (software rasterizer) build `opengl32.dll` beside your program's executable. Heck, on a machine without a proper graphics card it would be even acceptable to replace the system opengl32.dll (though this is not recommended).

Comment: Mesa softpipe... looking into it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the **OpenGL** section [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/Building_on_Microsoft_Windows)... and make sure u r using openscad 64 bit