# unable to run genymotion on windows azure cloude os. it saying to check video card

Tags: java, android, azure, virtualbox, genymotion

i am trying to install android sdk and genymotion on my cloud os(windows azure
when i try to run the genymotion it saying that "unable to start genymotion virtual device"
"check if your videocard support openGL"
what should i do to check video card supprot on clode os

Comment: There are no video card in Azure VMs.  Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21389451/how-do-i-fake-opengl-in-an-azure-virtual-machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

android-sdk tools emulator will work in azure .if it you have any issues with the speed of emulator loading time, you can have a vm with high configuration.